# How to open a new XAML page in the same window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I have two XAML pages and when you click a button in one, the other page opens. My code is:

```
private void cookingButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CookingMenu cooking = new CookingMenu();
    cooking.Show();
}
```

CookingMenu is the name of the XAML page. This code opens the page in a new window but is there any way to open the page in the same window? Both the pages are the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static MainWindow ParentWindowRef;
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MultiplePageOpeninSameScreen.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiplePageOpeninSameScreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <DockPanel>
        <Frame Name="ParentFrame"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ParentWindowRef = this;
    this.ParentFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
}
```

Page1.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="MultiplePageOpeninSameScreen.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiplePageOpeninSameScreen"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="TxtBlockSomeTxt" Text="This is Page One" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="BtnGoToPageTwo" Content="Go To Page 2" Click="BtnGoToPageTwo_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
private void BtnGoToPageTwo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ParentWindowRef.ParentFrame.Navigate(new Page2());
}
```

Page2.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="MultiplePageOpeninSameScreen.Page2"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiplePageOpeninSameScreen"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Page2">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="TxtBlockSomeTxt" Text="This is Page Two" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Grid.Row ="1" Name="BtnGoToPageOne" Content="Go To Page One" Click="BtnGoToPageOne_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Page2.xaml.cs

```
private void BtnGoToPageOne_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ParentWindowRef.ParentFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me the error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` I wasn't sure what to do with the main window related code because I only have the two windows.

Comment: Where are you getting the Object Reference Error ?; Where did you set your "Frame" control ?

Comment: I'm getting the error at the `App.ParentWindowRef.ParentFrame.Navigate(new CookingMenu());` line. I put the "Frame control" in the page 1 grid area.

Comment: Did u set your would be parent frame in app.xaml.cs file ? I think you are getting object reference error because of "ParentWindowRef" being null. Check you code once. You can use the MainWindow with a frame control like I did which can be used to load subsequent pages in that frame as you intent to.

Comment: I added the main window and moved the "Frame" control to that. I have set up the parent frame in app.xaml.cs but I still get the error. Do I need to change it all for my project specifically or can that exact line be used in any project?

Comment: You will set the MainWindow reference in App.Xaml.cs file only once and you can use it through out the application. In Main window loaded method make sure you set this `App.ParentWindowRef = this;`

Comment: I've done both of those but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173357/discussion-between-kishore-and-rory-danes).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `Frame` control here is the [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx)

Here is an great [example](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation) by Paul Stovell you should look into.

Comment: I followed the instructions and added the lines `<Frame x:Name="mainFrame" />` and `mainFrame.Navigate(new CookingMenu());` but now it gives the error `System.InvalidOperationException: ''RecipeOrganiser.CookingMenu' root element is not valid for navigation.'`

Comment: Are you sure it's a `Page` and not a window you have? :-)

Comment: Yeah, realised I'm using windows not pages

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way would be to use the Frame control as others have proposed here but I want to show a different way, it is possible to change the content of a window to another, try this code:

```
CookingMenu Testing = new CookingMenu();

private void cookingButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
this.Content = Testing.Content;
}
```